# PL/SQL To convert Day of Week 'D' from 1-7 to 0-6

Tags: plsql, oracle11g

The code below is a stored procedure that takes two parameters. For example  **sp_DATE_D(2000,2001)** and when you run a select statement in Application Express for one row it returns the following
DATE_KEY = 01/01/2000
FULL_DATE_DESCRIPTION = Saturday, January 1, 2000
DAY_OF_WEEK = 7 
I read that you can convert the day of week from 1 - 7 to 0 - 6. I believe its called crontab number. Not sure how to implement.

0 = Sunday
1 = Monday
2 = Tuesday
3 = Wednesday
4 = Thursday
5 = Friday
6 = Saturday

Table Definition:

```
CREATE TABLE DATE_D
(  
    DATE_KEY DATE NOT NULL,
    FULL_DATE_DESCRIPTION VARCHAR2(64) NOT NULL,
    DAY_OF_WEEK NUMBER(1,0) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT DATE_D_PK PRIMARY KEY (DATE_KEY)
);
```

Stored Procedure:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE sp_DATE_D(v_START_YEAR IN INT, v_END_YEAR IN INT) AS

v_CURRENT_DATE DATE;
v_END_DATE DATE;

BEGIN

v_CURRENT_DATE := TO_DATE('0101' || v_START_YEAR, 'MMDDYYYY');
v_END_DATE     := TO_DATE('1231' || v_END_YEAR, 'MMDDYYYY');

DELETE FROM DATE_D;

WHILE v_CURRENT_DATE <= v_END_DATE 
LOOP
INSERT INTO DATE_D
(
    DATE_KEY, 
    FULL_DATE_DESCRIPTION,
    DAY_OF_WEEK
)   
VALUES
(
    v_CURRENT_DATE,
    TO_CHAR(v_CURRENT_DATE, 'Day, Month DD, YYYY'),
    TO_CHAR(v_CURRENT_DATE, 'D')
);

v_CURRENT_DATE := v_CURRENT_DATE + 1;

END LOOP;
END;
/
```

Solution to post:

```
TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(v_CURRENT_DATE,'D')) - 1,
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't say what you are trying to achieve. Where did you get the sp did you write it?

If you want to get day of week -1 you can just insert

```
to_number(to_char(v_current_date,'D'))-1
```

Comment: I wrote the stored procedure myself and I'm doing it this way for own learning. This is for a data warehouse. So what you see in my post, my return value, what is happening is that between the two parameters the table will be populated with dates from day one of the START_YEAR to last day of the END_YEAR. My stored procedure will contain more columns, but I figure to start little by little and work on the errors as I build on the code.

Comment: So you just need to take one off the number returned as above?

Comment: That piece worked fine. To think what I had tried was to_char(v_current_date - 1,'D'). Thanks a bunch!